# Terraform expand map variable to independent parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've the following variable:

```
variable "mymap" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "key1" = "val1"
    "key2" = "val2"
  }
}
```

I am trying to expand this to create individual parameters in this resource:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "default" {
  name   = "cache-params"
  family = "redis2.8"

  parameter {
    name  = "activerehashing"
    value = "yes"
  }

  parameter {
    name  = "min-slaves-to-write"
    value = "2"
  }
}
```

My desired state for this example would be:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "default" {
  name   = "cache-params"
  family = "redis2.8"

  parameter {
    name  = "key1"
    value = "val1"
  }

  parameter {
    name  = "key2"
    value = "val2"
  }
}
```

I don't see this supported explicitly in the docs; am I even taking the correct approach to doing this?

(I'm mainly looking at leveraging 'dynamic' and 'for_each' keywords, but haven't been able to have success)

Comment: What do you mean by expand? There are multiple ways you could do this but I need to understand what exactly you want. Where should `mymap` be used?

Comment: Added desired state; I'm open to not using the map and just passing json in to variable defining this as well; just need to get the terraform side to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired state, you would have to do a couple of things. One could be to use `dynamic` meta-argument [1] with `for_each` [2]. The code would have to be changed to the following:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "default" {
  name   = "cache-params"
  family = "redis2.8"

  dynamic "parameter" {
    for_each = var.mymap
    content {
      name  = parameter.value.name
      value = parameter.value.value
    }
  }
}
```

However, you would also have to adjust the variable:

```
variable "mymap" {
  type        = map(map(string))
  description = "Map of parameters for Elasticache."

  default = {
    "parameter1" = {
      "value" = "value1"
      "name"  = "name1"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can define the values for the variable `mymap` in a tfvars file (e.g., `terraform.tfvars`) like this:

```
mymap = {
  "parameter1" = {
    "name"  = "activerehashing"
    "value" = "yes"
  }
  "parameter2" = {
    "name"  = "min-slaves-to-write"
    "value" = "2"
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`dynamic` block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) to dynamically declare zero or more nested configuration blocks based on a collection.

```
resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "default" {
  name   = "cache-params"
  family = "redis2.8"

  dynamic "parameter" {
    for_each = var.mymap
    content {
      name  = parameter.key
      value = parameter.value
    }
  }
}
```

The above tells Terraform to generate one `parameter` block for each element of `var.varmap`, and to populate the `name` and `value` arguments of each generated block based on the key and value from each map element respectively.

The `parameter` symbol inside the `content` block represents the current element of the collection. This symbol is by default named after the block type being generated, which is why it was named `parameter` in this case. It's possible to override that generated name using an additional `iterator` argument in the `dynamic` block, but that's necessary only if you are generating multiple levels of nesting where a nested block type has the same name as its container.